# Check to see if a div exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <span></span>

    <div class="content" id="2">
    <div class="reply"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="1">
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="3">
        <div class"reply"></div>
    </div>

        <script>
        var n = $( ".reply" ).length; 
        $( "span" ).text( "There are " + n + " divs.");
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to write a jQuery script that will check individual divs with unique id's to see if it contains the "reply" div. I have code to see if the "reply" div exists at all working. I am new to jQuery so I am unsure how to go about this.

```
var n = $( ".reply" ).length; 
        $( "span" ).text( "There are " + n + " divs.");
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/SdRYd/1/ (although you forgot the `=` in `<div class"reply"`)

Comment: Your approach is totally fine. See also [Is there an "exists" function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `#uniqueId .reply` jQuery selector:

```
alert("The id with id '3' contains" + $("#3 .reply").length + ".reply divs.");
```

Comment: @Yamaha32088 You are welcome. :-) I have a [Yamaha PSR8000 keyboard](http://www.youtube.com/IonicaBizau). ;-)

Answer (score 3):

To check if a particular Id containing .reply div:

```
if($("#id .reply").length>0)
{
//reply exist in this id
}
```

Above code works like this

```
$("#id .reply").length
```

returns the occurrence of `.reply` in `#id` selector.

If present then return 1 else return 0.

Comment: or just `if($("#id .reply").length)` +1

Answer (score 1):

You are on correct path, if you want to check for unique id use `#elementId`

```
if($("#ID .reply").length > 0)
{
   //div exists
}
```